# set report viewer parameters programmatically

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I have this method which through it, I guess it fills reportviewer parameters, but when I evaluate ReportParameters, (this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.GetParameters()), the first parameter has value of all others parameters. What's wrong here? this code belongs to FrmReport(example):

```
public void SetReportParameters(params string[] parameters){
    if (parameters.Length == ReportParameters.Count)
    {
        //ReportParameters = this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.GetParameters();
        ReportParameterCollection pCol = new ReportParameterCollection();
        int i = 0;
        parameters.ToList().ForEach(p => {
            pCol.Add(new ReportParameter(ReportParameters[i].Name, p));
        });
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(pCol);
    }
}
```

Then I say on another form:

```
var frmReport = new FrmReport();
frmReport.SetReportParameters("1","2");
```

And there I get the result like I said before.

Comment: "the first parameter has value of all others parameters." - what do you mean by that ?

Comment: Couple valid answers below.  And also, your call to `SetReportParameters` will not even compile.  The stub requires `string[]` but you are passing it `string string`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would fall under a "misuse of ForEach" category.  You are never incrementing `i` first of all (that I can see) which is your main problem.  The major disadvantage to `.ToList().ForEach()` is it's poor readability.

I think you would be better off just using loops first until you are getting the results you want, *then if you really must* go ahead and convert to LINQ.

```
    var pCol = new ReportParameterCollection();
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
    {
        pCol.Add(new ReportParameter(ReportParameters[i].Name, parameters[i]);
    }
```

Really not sure why you are checking the length of `ReportParameters` and `parameters`.  The code is fairly unclear and your intent is not written out that I can see.  But I would "un-optimize" this code so that it is easier to step through in the debugger then go for optimization later when your method is working properly.

Comment: Oh my god, my mistake, that's happend whe U work under stress, Thanks Evan, I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem with ForEach is solved.

```
int i = 0;
parameters.ToList().ForEach(p => {
    pCol.Add(new ReportParameter(ReportParameters[i].Name, p));
    i++;
});
```